# MSXML2: How can I get text of a node if any child node in between parent node?

Tags: msxml

I have this node:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr node; 
node->Getxml() returns  "<para>this is sample para which has newline<b/>coming</para>"
```

but when i use `node->Gettext();` it returns

> this is sample para which has newlinecoming

I want get this as

```
"this is sample para which has newline\ncoming"
```

here `<b/>` represent newline.

1. List item

How can I get this newline character inserted?

Comment: Improved formatting. But I think the question needs more clarity.

Comment: I think you'll have to use the `nodeValue` property, not the `text` one. But then, you'll have to process child nodes yourself. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762687%28v%3dvs.85%29 as a starting point. You should also add a language tag.

Comment: How can i get string with line break inserted wherever  <b/> is there: